# How to calculate protobuf size?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Couldn't find a nice and easy way to calculate my protobuf sizes using python. Is there a recommended way?

I am sending my protobufs into rabbitmq, and huge messages causing my connection to break. I want to be able to validate the size before sending a message.